# Html button stops working after code run

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game in HTML and JavaScript. I have a button that the user presses to 'run' a command they entered. But, after they have 'connected' to an ip the button no longer works, there is no error in the console. How can I fix this?

```js
var ip = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.4"]
var gip;
var log;
var compname;
var svirus;
var connected = false;

function runcmd() {
  var user = document.getElementById('code').value;
  if (user == 'clear') {
    l1.innerHTML = '';
    l2.innerHTML = '';
    l3.innerHTML = '';
    l4.innerHTML = '';
    l5.innerHTML = '';
    l6.innerHTML = '';
    l7.innerHTML = '';
    l8.innerHTML = '';
    l9.innerHTML = '';
    l10.innerHTML = '';
  };
  if (user == 'connect') {
    gip = prompt('Enter The Targets IP: ');
    for (var key in ip) {
      var user = document.getElementById('code').value;
      if (ip[key] == gip) {
        l1.innerHTML = 'Connecting to ' + gip;
        l2.innerHTML = 'Connected to ' + gip;
        connected = true;
        grant.play()
        l3.innerHTML = 'view bank';
        l4.innerHTML = 'upload [virus]';
        l5.innerHTML = 'disconnect [ip]';
        var user = document.getElementById('code').value;
        if (user == 'disconnect' + gip) {
          connected = false;
          l1.innerHTml = 'Disconnected Safely...';
        };
        if (user == 'view bank') {
          var pwrd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
          var nam = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
          alert(pwrd);
          alert(nam);
          var uname = 'user' + nam;
          var user = prompt('Username: ');
          var pass = prompt('Password: ');
          if (user == uname && pass == pwrd) {
            console.log('hello')
          };
          if (user == 'upload') {
            svirus = prompt('Enter Virus: ');
            for (var key in boughtviruses) {
              if (boughtviruses[key] == svirus) {
                l1.innerHTML = 'Uploading ' + svirus;
                l2.innerHTML = 'Virus Uploaded';
              }
              else {
                alert("You Don't Have This Virus!");
              };
            };
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
};
```

```html
<span class="span" id="l1"></span><br />
<span class="span" id="l2"></span><br />
<span class="span" id="l3"></span><br />
<span class="span" id="l4"></span><br />
<span class="span" id="l5"></span><br />
<span class="span" id="l6"></span><br />
<span class="span" id="l7"></span><br />
<span class="span" id="l8"></span><br />
<span class="span" id="l9"></span><br />
<span class="span" id="l10"></span><br />
<span >C:\></span>
<input onclick="this.select()" id="code" class="inp" />
<button id="runcodeuser" onclick="runcmd()">Send Command</button>
```

Comment: What are l1,l2,l3.......

Comment: i tried ur code and after it is connected i got ti\his error in the console   {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: grant is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 54,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: How do you know the button no longer works ? Maybe it works (runs the runcmd() again) but the bug is in runcmd() . . .

Comment: Hi I think you should go through if else conditions. I found your most of the written conditions will not satisfy atleast once.

Comment: If I create a new function to hold the other IF statements and call it after l5 has been changed would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an event dispatcher. Every possible `user` input would be a separate event.
Separate the code to handle each event into different functions.

For example:

```
function user_clear () { ... }
function user_connect () { ... }
function user_bank () { ... }
function user_upload () { ... }

function dispatch_event (user)
{
  switch (user)
  {
    case 'clear': user_clear (); break;
    case 'connect': user_connect (); break;
    case 'view bank': user_bank (); break;
    case 'upload': user_upload (); break;
    default: console.log ('dispatch_event: no such event: ' + user);
  }
}
```

Then call it from runcmd():

```
function runcmd() {
  var user = document.getElementById('code').value;
  dispatch_event (user);
}
```

And also after running grant.play():  (inside user_connnect())

```
grant.play();
var user = document.getElementById('code').value;
dispatch_event (user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your code only two "commands" are actually usable - *clear* and *connect*.

If the command, that is the value of the textbox, is *connect*, the browser will ask for the "targets IP". It then iterates through the IPs in the array declared at the top, and in each iteration again sets the variable `user` to the textbox value - but the textbox will still contain *connect*, and also the `user`-variable is already declared, so there's no need to user the `var` keyword again.

Because of this `user == "view bank"` for example will never evaluate to true. You'll have to restructure your code considerably for this to work as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your `runcmd()` function only has 3 blocks:

```
var user...
if (user=="clear") { ... }
if (user=="connect") { ... }
```

Everything else is in that last block/line. If `user=="connect"` is true, then the block executes, but `user=="view bank"`, etc. will never be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no semicolon after `grant.play()` - and this function doesn't seem to be defined anywhere inside your code.

Also, for what it's worth, I do get an error message when running the snippet:

```
{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}
```

Comment: [Semicolons are optional in JavaScript](http://mislav.net/2010/05/semicolons/) :)